# iPhone & iPad position: fixed bottom problem

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

http://t1.kameleo.ch/

if you scroll down you will find a login button under the footer. If you click it, the login appears on the bottom of the screen.

I have done this with a negative fixed positioning relative to the bottom of the page. This works fine in every browser, expect for mobile devices such as the iPad and the iPhone. The login bar appears on the middle of the screen.

Screenshot on iPhone:
http://img844.imageshack.us/i/photoe.png/

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons this happens is that the iOS browsers use a viewport that moves around the window, that means that fixed position is fixed in regards to the window, but not the viewport. You'll need to position it using JavaScript by checking the current viewport position.

Comment: could you show me an example? I have not a lot experience with viewpoints. How would this look like?

Comment: i have found this pure css solution that works for me: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1):

Set the position to absolute; and add this:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
  $('#loginwindow').animate({top: $(document).scrollTop()}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution. I didn't try yet, but it should work:

//stick the footer at the bottom of the page if we're on an iPad/iPhone due to viewport/page bugs in mobile webkit

```
if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod')
{
         $("#footer").css("position", "static");
};
```