# CSS background fixed positioning in iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I'm developing a web app in which I'm using a div#details as pop-up to deliver content.

The div has the following CSS properties

```
 #detail {
        position: fixed;
        background: #F2F2F2;
        height: 450px;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 125px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 880px;
        padding: 30px;
    }
```

This div appears on clicking on an article.

When I click on any article, on a browser in a computer, the pop-up appears in the correct position (always 125px from top of the browser);

But when I view the same page on an iPad, if I scroll down the page & clicked on an article, the pop-up appears 125px from the begining of the document (not of the browser) like absolute positioning.

How do I fix this I want the pop-up to stay in the visible screen.

**Update:**

The markup is like

```
<body> 
     <div id="opaque_layer" class="hide"></div> 
     <div class="container_12"> 
     <div id="detail" class=" hide grid_12_custom"></div>
         <!-- lots of other divs -->
</body>
```

Please notice, after scrolling, the pop-up goes up too!!
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or at least the html where the #detail is, together with the CSS?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a iPad bug. There's a recommendation to calculate position with javascript.
[iPhone & iPad position: fixed bottom problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404972/iphone-ipad-position-fixed-bottom-problem)